# Changing body background color with angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I want to be able to change the background color of `<body>` depending on what the current path is.

I tried doing it by checking $location.path() whenever the path was changed and then using the `ng-style` directive to change the background color but this seems like a hack (and didn't work).

What would be a more decoupled way to achieve this?

Here's the code I wrote if anyone wants to see it.

```
app.controller('backgroundCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$route', '$location', function($rootScope, $scope, $route, $location){
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){

    if ($location.path() == '/'){
      $scope.backgroundStyle = {background: '#ffffff'};
    } else {
      $scope.backgroundStyle = {background: '#000000'};
    }

  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To decouple such a dynamic change in style, data, content and etc., it is often practical to create another angular module that contains an interface(Custom Provider) that can give you access to these changes before and after the configuration level. Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wpokUS9qpXlqsMopqIZT?p=preview) to provide a view of what I'll be discussing below.

For this answer, I have created a small module(route-data.js) with a `provider`, RouteData, which exposes
two function configurations:

`applyConfig()` - assigns settings to be accessed in the RouteData service.
`hookToRootScope()` - hooks the RouteData service in the `$rootScope` hence making it available to all child scopes to be created and the entire application.

The RouteData provider has a `RouteData()` service that provides access to methods which sets and gets `RouteData` settings that will be provided in the `$routeProvider` configuration.

(If you're not familiar with providers and services, read more about it [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers))

(If you're not familiar with the `config()` and `run()` methods, you can read more in [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module))

**route-data.js**

```
angular.module('RouteData', []).

provider('RouteData', function () {
  var settings = {};
  var hookToRootScope = false;

  this.applyConfig = function(newSettings) {
    settings = newSettings;
  };

  this.hookToRootScope = function(enableRootScopeHook) {
    hookToRootScope = enableRootScopeHook;
  };

  function RouteData() {

    this.set = function(index, value) {
      settings[index] = value;
    };

    this.get = function(index) {
      if(settings.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
        return settings[index];
      } else {
        console.log('RouteData: Attempt to access a propery that has not been set');
      }
    };

    this.isHookedToRootSope = function() {
      return hookToRootScope;
    };
  }

  this.$get = function() {
      return new RouteData();
  };
}).

run(['$location', '$rootScope', 'RouteData', function($location, $rootScope, RouteData) {
  if(RouteData.isHookedToRootSope()) {
    $rootScope.RouteData = RouteData;
  }

  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, current, previous) {
    var route = current.$$route;
    if(typeof(route) !== 'undefined' && typeof(route['RouteData']) !== 'undefined') {
      var data = route['RouteData'];
      for(var index in data)
        RouteData.set(index, data[index]);
    } 
  });
}]);
```

The script below shows how to use the RouteData Module above via injecting the RouteDataProvider in the configuration level and apply default configurations such as the `bodyStyle` via `RouteDataProvider.applyConfig()`, you may also add more settings before the application is fully running. Hook it up in the $rootScope by setting `RouteDataProvider.hookToRootScope()` to true. Lastly, appending data, `RouteData` e.g.

```
RouteData: {
      bodyStyle: {
        'background-color': 'green'
      }
    }
```

to be sent in by the $routeProvider and processed by the `run()` method defined in the RouteData module which initializes the settings for the RouteData services to be accessed in the application.

**script.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'RouteData']).

config(['$routeProvider', 'RouteDataProvider', function($routeProvider, RouteDataProvider) {
  RouteDataProvider.applyConfig({
    bodyStyle: {
      'background-color': 'white'
    }
  });

  RouteDataProvider.hookToRootScope(true);

  $routeProvider.when('/landing', {
    RouteData: {
      bodyStyle: {
        'background-color': 'green'
      }
    },
    templateUrl: 'landing.html',
    controller: 'LandingController'  
  }).when('/login', {
    RouteData: {
     bodyStyle: {
         'background-color': 'gray',
         padding: '10px',
         border: '5px solid black',
         'border-radius': '1px solid black'
     }
    },
    templateUrl: 'login.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/landing'
  });

}]).

controller('LoginController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]).

controller('LandingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

So the final piece of code to be added in your index page or any other page would be something like this.

A portion of `index.html`

```
<body ng-style="RouteData.get('bodyStyle')"> 
    <a href="#/landing">Landing</a> | 
    <a href="#/login">Login</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

Comment: There's a typo that causes this to crash. this.hookeToRootScope should be this.hookToRootScope

Answer (score 4):

One way to style the body is to add `ng-view` as a body attribute, then use `ng-class` or `ng-style` (I did not use any other option to date).

For example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="my-app">
  <head>
    <title>My Site</title>
    <script src="angular/angular.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-class="{login:loginBody}" ng-view>
    <script src="my-app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this example, the `login` class is applied to the body only when `loginBody` is a true value in the current scope, set in a login controller.

This is much less flexible than the approach offered by @ryeballar. It may just be enough in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that when I navigate to another page without page reload background color still remains, so I am doing this (I am using angular **ui-router**):

**In config:**

```
$stateProvider.state('app.login',{
            url: '/login',
            onExit: function($rootScope){
                $rootScope.bodyClass = 'body-one';
            },
           templateUrl: 'ng/templates/auth/login-page-one.html',
            controller: function($rootScope){
                $rootScope.bodyClass = 'body-two';
            }
        })

        .state('app.signup',{
            url: '/signup',
            onExit: function($rootScope){
                $rootScope.bodyClass = 'body-one';
            },
            templateUrl: 'ng/templates/auth/signup-page-one.html',
            controller: function($rootScope){
                $rootScope.bodyClass = 'body-two';
            }
        });
```

**In the Template**

```
<body class="{{bodyClass ? bodyClass : 'body-one'}}">
```

**In CSS:**

```
.body-one{
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: #f0f4fb;
}

.body-two{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #2e9fff;
}
```