# Set body class="" attribute to $scope member value directly

Tags: angularjs

I want to set the `<body class="">` attribute value directly based on my `$scope.bodyClass` member, however this doesn't work:

#### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
     <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/application.js"></script>
     <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-class="{{bodyClass}}">
    <div ng-view></div>
    <p>{{foo}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Controllers.js

```
var myControllers = angular.module("myControllers", []);
myControllers.controller("HomeController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

    $scope.foo = "bar";
    $scope.bodyClass = "home";
}]);
```

#### Application.js

```
var applicationModule = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute", "LocalStorageModule", "myControllers"]);

applicationModule.config(
    ["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when("/home", {
                templateUrl: "views/home.html",
                controller: "HomeController"
            });
    }]
);
```

When I run it, Chrome's DOM inspector reports that the `class=""` attribute isn't set to anything.

Comment: And what if you put `ng-view` attribute on `body` itself?

Comment: @Cherniv I understand that would replace the contents of `<body>`, which I don't want.

Comment: Try to put bodyClass in a run block and you can get the current route on routeSuccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you're setting inside your controller is only available in the DOM that is scoped inside it. The body tag is outside of that scope. You can inject $rootScope into your controller and set the bodyClass on it to get this to work.

The scope of your controller is based upon where the ng-view is placed.

Answer (score 1):

I have posted an answer from an [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656847/changing-body-background-color-with-angularjs/22663673#22663673) not too long ago, that may help you solve this problem.

Basically you create a provider that fetches data from the $routeProvider when the applications runs and changes the current route, you append additional data to the `when()` and fetch it on `run()` and have the provider change it according to the route specified.

Additionally, you can use it in your controller by injecting the service associated by the provider. Here is a small example to achieve that.

```
controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'RouteData', function($scope, RouteData) {
  RouteData.set('bodyClass', 'Home');
}]);
```

and your **config()** should look something like this.

```
config(function($routeProvider, RouteData) {
 RouteData.applyConfig({
  bodyClass: 'Home'
 });

 RouteData.hookToRootScope(true);

 $routeProvider.when('/home', {
   RouteData: {bodyClass: 'Home'},
   templateUrl: 'home.html',
   controller: 'HomeController'   
 });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-class="RouteData.get('bodyClass')">
```

Update:
Sorry I provided the wrong SO Question Link.. [here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656847/changing-body-background-color-with-angularjs/22663673#22663673)..