# AngularJS - Apply full screen background colour to partial

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am using AngularJS to create a one page app.

I am simply trying to apply CSS styles such that all partials have different background colour but I want the colours to cover the full screen instead of just covering a portion of the screen.

Better explained using the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/m0mhXbzg43tlzaiAg863?p=preview

How can I achieve this? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way CSS height's work in percents is it'll will do the percent of the height of the parents element, so in your case the parent is 'ng-scope' and that's why your element 'search' is giving you a 100% height of the parent element ('ng-scope'), to fix this remove the parent surrounding your search element and then that will use the body as the parent so you could so something like this,

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.search { height: 100%;}
```

Hope that makes sense and helps you out!

**EDIT**

I just, realized you're using Angular so in your case you could simply add a class like so to your parent,

**HTML**

```
<div class="full" ng-view></div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.full { height: 100%;}
```

Comment: Updated with the CSS you suggested but no luck. http://plnkr.co/edit/m0mhXbzg43tlzaiAg863?p=preview

Comment: You'll need to add width: 100% and height 100% to html and body elements

Comment: Ah perfect! Thank you very much. New things to learn every day.

Answer (score 2):

I have posted an answer from an [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656847/changing-body-background-color-with-angularjs/22663673#22663673) not too long ago, that may help you solve this problem. Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wpokUS9qpXlqsMopqIZT?p=preview) for that answer.

Basically you create a provider that fetches data from the $routeProvider when the applications runs and changes the current route, you append additional data to the when() and fetch it on run() and have the provider change it according to the route specified.

Additionally, you can use it in your controller by injecting the service associated by the provider. Here is a small example to achieve that. Note that bodyClass is a class that might be used for the `<body>` class.

```
controller('HomeController', ['$scope', 'RouteData', function($scope, RouteData) {
  RouteData.set('bodyClass', 'Home');
}]);
```

and your config() should look something like this.

```
config(function($routeProvider, RouteData) {
  RouteData.applyConfig({
  bodyClass: 'Home'
}); 

RouteData.hookToRootScope(true);

 $routeProvider.when('/home', {
   RouteData: {bodyClass: 'Home'},
   templateUrl: 'home.html',
   controller: 'HomeController'   
 });
});
```

HTML

```
<body ng-class="RouteData.get('bodyClass')">
```

Comment: This is a very elegant way to dynamically apply CSS styles. I will give this a go as well! Thanks