# Adding full page background to a single view in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I need to add a  fullscreen CSS background to a single view in my app. I tried to achieve this by adding a class to the `body` however this remains in the cache and remains on the body when switching view.

I'm having this issue because my `<div ng-view=""></div>` is within the `<body>` so I cannot easily add a fullscreen BG from within the view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing body background color with angularjs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656847/changing-body-background-color-with-angularjs).

Comment: So many ways to do this ... directive, class on template, `ng-class `on `ng-view`

Answer (score 1):

For a very quick simple answer this is what I did.

applied conditional class to `ng-view`

**index.html**

`ng-class="{'homebg' : home}"`

**style.scss**

`.homebg {
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url('../images/home-bg.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
}`

**Controller.js**

`$scope.home = true;`